# How do you start looping at a certain key within an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, javascript-objects

```
$.each( data[0], function( key, value ) {
      console.log( key + ": " + value );
})
```

I want the loop to start at a certain key within this object. I do not want to console.log every single key and value within this object.

Comment: Object keys are in arbitrary order so this question is pure fantasy!

Comment: There's no order to keys, so it makes no sense to start at a particular key.

Comment: If you want to skip some keys, use `if` or `switch` statements to test `key`.

Comment: Oh okay I see your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object keys aren't iterated through in any order, but you can conditionally console.log if you want values from certain keys:

```js
var obj = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  longerKey: 3,
  anotherLongerKey: 4
};

keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  if(key.length > 4) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can dump the loop and use `obj.two` directly :)

Comment: @kuroineko You're right. I changed my code example to be a better use of the conditional.

Comment: Looks better now :)

Answer (score 1):

> There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any
>   particular order.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Answer (score 0):

A key can be any string value, and the order `for ... in` browses through them is not guaranteed.
Behind the scene, the key/property association uses a hash table, and `for ... in` will loop through the properties according to the way the hash function spreads their keys, i.e. a completely arbitrary, pseudo-random repartition.

If you want the properties to be browsed in whatever order (lexicographic or numeric), you will have to extract the keys into an array, then sort this array.
You will then have to eliminate the unwanted keys, either by cropping the key array or testing the key values within the browsing loop.

That sounds like a lot of work to me, but surely you have your reasons...